# Shell script to read and write to a file

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a script which contains the file location and i am running a command to fix the files.
But i am not able to write the output to a file.

```
#!/bin/ksh
while read line
do
`shnfix "$line"` >> output.txt
done < filename.txt
```

The output generated after adding set -x in the beginning of the script.

`+ < filename.txt
+ read line
+ shnfix /x01/naveen_wav/file1.wav
+ >> output.txt
Fixing [/x01/naveen_wav/file1.wav] (3:49.42) --> [file1-fixed.wav] : 100% OK
Padded last file with 1194 zero-bytes.
+ read line
+ shnfix /x01/naveen_wav/file2.wav
+ >> output.txt
Fixing [/x01/naveen_wav/file2.wav] (4:30.35) --> [file2-fixed.wav] : 100% OK
Padded last file with 644 zero-bytes.
+ read line`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Please use code block for your script so that it is readable.

Comment: I am unable to write the output to a file.

Comment: try to remove the external quotes. Keep only: shnfix "$line" >> output.txt

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient version (I/O wise) of @gile's code:

```
#!/bin/ksh
filename="/path/to/filename.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    shnfix "$line"
done < filename.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The output should be inside `

```
`shnfix $line >> output.txt`
```

So the script could be like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
filename="/path/to/filename.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
        # display line or do somthing on $line
        echo "$line"
        `shnfix $line >> output.txt`
done <"$fileName"
```

Comment: putting it inside backquotes will do nothing since the output is being written to a file.  It doesn't solve any problem - it makes the process a lot slower because shnfix has to run in a subshell.

Comment: I tired tried with your change,but not able to write the output to a file

Comment: the output is printed on the screen. i want output in a text file.I have huge files that needs to be run and i want output of all the files to be stored in a file to review thee fix done on all the files

Comment: Are you sure shnfix is writing to stdout and not stderr?  Run "shnfix _sample_file > temp" on command line and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the backticks, they are at least confusing.

Written as it is the shell will exeute the command in a subshell and try to execute the result, adding the redirection to it.
I assume you don't want to execute the output, but you want to redirect the output.

If the output starts with, for example `line`, that is a correct unix command, which does not create output you don't see an error, but neither the output.

I get a `test.ksh[4]: line1: not found [No such file or directory]` where 'line1' is the first line in my test file.

Or keep it in a block and redirect all output from it. Makes the intention more clear and it is easier to add commnds.

```
#!/bin/ksh
filename="/path/to/filename.txt"
{
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    shnfix "$line"
  done < "$filename"
} > output.txt
```

http://www.shellcheck.net (a big troubleshooter)   will give similar hints